# Can't run TileStache on Windows

Tags: tilestache

I enter following command: `tilestache-server.py`

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\TileStache-1.49.8\tilestache-server.py", line 49, in <module>
import TileStache
File "...\TileStache-1.49.8\TileStache\__init__.py", line 266
except Core.KnownUnknown, e:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

PS. When I enter: `python setup.py install`.

I got a bounch of

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the versions. Installed python 2.7, previous I got 3.5.